# ant getResourceAsStream null but ok in Eclipse

Tags: java, ant

I've been trying to fix this for ages but here goes :
I have a text file that gets loaded fine when I run my java code with getResourceAsStream within Eclipse.

The text file is in the same package dir as the class that uses it.
however , when I run the same code from command line with ant , getResourceAsStream returns null.

I figure it is class path related but I can't seem to get it going from tinkering with my build.xml or directory structure

Any help appreciated, thanks, Jamesie

Comment: Please show your Ant task, and ideally the code too.

Comment: Hope you are not moving that txt file to compiled classes folder ex:`bin\com\xxx\urtext.txt` while you compile your classes.

Comment: here is  my ant target :

Comment: <target name="runTests" depends="compile">
   <taskdef resource= "testngtasks" classpathref= "classpath"/>
   <testng classpathref="classpath" outputDir="${results.root}" suitename="Test" testname="Test">
    <xmlfileset dir= "." includes="Tests.xml"/>
    <jvmarg value="-ea" />
    <sysproperty  key="propFile" value="${propFile}"/>
   </testng>
  </target>

Comment: and here is my code ( for a testNG dataprovider ) :InputStream resourceStream = DataProviderStuff.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)

Comment: btw , it all works as above , as I have taken out depends=clean, but I'd like to do clean and compile

Comment: last info from build.xml: <path id="classpath">
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="build/classes"/>
 </path>

Comment: Jamesie, please add the info into the question directly, not as comments. This way it will be easier to read, you'll see a big difference yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it took me a while to solve it.
I also thought that the problem was coming from `getResourceAsStream()`, or from the relative path in the parameters, but **NO** !

It is much simpler than that : the file doesn't exist.

You can check if you want : go to your *.jar file* that you generated with ant, and unzip it (using 7zip, WinRAR or whatever..). You will see that your config.properties file is NOT there.

Indeed, if just used `<jar />` in your *build.xml* file (the input for ant), it will compress only the *.java* files !
You need to use copy as well :

```
<target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${res.dir}"
                     includes="**/*.properties,**/*.xml,**/*.png,**/*.jpg" />
            <!-- I advise you to also include .xml .jpg, ... or any file you need that doesn't end with .java--> 
        </copy>
</target>
```

And that's it, you can now check that config.properties is included in your final *.jar* file, by unzipping it again.